# Why React Class Component and Function Component output is different in setTimeout?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

A class component and a function component, both of which can click on the div to modify the value of num.

```js
export default function App() {
  const [num, setNum] = useState(0);
  const click = () => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log(num, "3000");
    }, 3000);
    setNum(num + 1);
  };

  return <div onClick={click}>click {num}</div>;
}
```

```js
export default class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    num: 0
  };

  click = () => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log(this.state.num);
    }, 3000);
    this.setState({ num: this.state.num + 1 });
  };

  render() {
    return <div onClick={this.click}>click {this.state.num}</div>;
  }
}
```

Why is the output of num different in the above two components after clicking

Answer (score 3):

In class components, when state is set, when the component updates, the new state will be assigned to the `state` property of the instance. To oversimplify, doing

```
this.setState(someNewState);
```

eventually results in React doing something like

```
theInstance.state = mergedNewState;
```

As a result, referencing `this.state` will result in changes being seen if the state updates, because `this.state` points to something new..

---

Functional components are different. Unlike class components, nothing gets (visibly) mutated when using their state. Instead, when you call a state setter, the whole function (component) runs again, and the calls to `useState` return a new value.

In your code, the

```
const [num, setNum] = useState(0);
```

results in a `num` that the `click` function [closes over.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work). If there's a click, when the timeout callback runs, it'll still close over the same `num` that was created before the click handler runs. The component will re-render with a new `click` function, which has a new `num` number that it closes over, but the old `click` function will still be referencing the `num` from the render in which that old function was created.